# How do we identify valid user in python script, If I want to let my script to be run by specific number of users

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, operating-system, environment-variables, python-3.6

I tried using `os.environ.get("USER")` function as I had this data for all the users I want to allow.

```py
var = os.environ.get("USER")

if var in data:
    pass
```

But a user can change this env variable

```
export USER=allowed_name
```

Is there any other way to check the user's validity?

Comment: Make them authenticate, e.g. using a password?